# A more elegant way to find the Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

Let  $f$ be defined analytically as : $$f(x)=\arccos \left ( \sin \left ( 2x \right ) \right ), x \in\left (0,10  \right ], f(x)=0, x\notin\left ( 0,10 \right ]$$

Here is a graph of the above function: [image]

The way I've come to solve this is to simply split the integral in the Fourier transform into pieces(the part where $f$ is non-zero), and do the calculations, but that is a tedious way of doing it. Do you have any suggestions how to retrieve the transform more quickly?

**EDIT:** As I am only getting into Fourier analysis, I don't know many tricks. However I've been researching, and one interesting topic came up, the DFT. Is it applicable in this case?

**Edit #2**: Unfortunately, At the moment my time is very limited and I can't afford to go into too much detail. If someone has the answer in terms of the standard properties of this transform, or maybe even an idea different from what Jack suggested in his first comment, post it. I am really eager to see how this can be done. I suppose, we will learn about this in year 2 of college, in the Signals class.

**EDIT #3:** Is it possible to invoke some other transform and use it to obtain the Fourier transform?

Comment: You may compute the Fourier transforms of your function restricted to $[0,\pi/4],[\pi/4,3\pi/4],[3\pi/4,5\pi/4],[11\pi/4,10]$ (it is just a linear function on these intervals). By summing translates you will recover the Fourier transform of the initial wave.

Comment: if this was not a completely randomly truncated function, you could use linearity and shift properties. But this function is hopeless, best to do it from scratch.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That is what I stated in the question.  However, during an examination I doubt I'll have that much time to do it.

Comment: Another possible approach is to restrict the initial function over $[0,3\pi]$ and $[3\pi,10]$ and sum these two Fourier transforms.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Feel free to post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use the fourier transform of continuous triangular wave, multiply it by a rectangular wave in time doman, which would then become a sinc convolution in frequency domain.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: Fourier *transform* of a periodic function, is its fourier series coefficients represented as delta functions. http://nptel.ac.in/courses/IIT-MADRAS/Principles_Of_Communication/pdf/Lecture07_FTPeriodic.pdf Then you can multiply the whole thing with a rectangular function to make the rest of the function zero, so that only [0,10] remains. Due to convolution theorem, you can convolve the fourier transform of the function with rectangular functions fourier transform, which is sinc. I would do it from the scratch though. However, this is a very useful thing to know, because usually it works well.

Answer (score 1):

If (for whatever reason) you are able to see that the image under $\Delta=d^2/dx^2$ is ... what it is: a linear combination of $\delta$ and its derivative at $0$, but just multiples of $\delta$ at the other "corners", then you can use the distributional "symmetry" of $\Delta$ and the fact that $e^{i\xi x}$ is an eigenfunction:
$$
\int e^{-ix\xi}\cdot \hbox{your function $f$}\;dx
\;=\; \int {\Delta e^{-ix\xi} \over -\xi^2}\cdot f(x)\;dx
\;=\; {1\over -\xi^2} \langle e^{-ix\xi},\;\hbox{that image by $\Delta$}\rangle
$$
This is just a slightly dressed-up integration by parts, but (if one can see how things fit together) saves some work by cancelling several terms up-front.

Comment: What does $\xi$ represent here?

Comment: @Shemafied, the $\xi$ is just my name for the output variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your graph consists of

1) Triangles, which has FT of squares of (reshaped) sinc function;

2) Triangles then shifted infinitely many times, which corresponds to convolving with Shah function. Since the FT of Shah is another Shah, the FT of the the infinitely shifted triangles becomes a squared sinc multiplied by Shah, which is effectively a sampling.

3) Then it is multiplied by a square, which corresponds to convolving with a sinc in the frequency domain.

I am not sure if there is a nice closed form, but this seems to be a standard way of approaching it.